# Firebase Auth js 400 bad request

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have created an web app using React Js and using firebase as database. It's working fine somtime and sometime it throws following error and takes too much time to load the data.

```
POST https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=AIzaSyDiQyIT5cn5_zyA4777R888g4wgmKeFZOw-dA 400
```

I am not able to figure out why it's working some time and does not work sometime. I have attached the console error's screen shot.

Even after getting this error I am able to retrive the data and write the data in firebase but it takes too much time to perform the operation.

I would really appriciate if someone could provide solution.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to give use more details: which database are you using: Firebase RTDB or firestore? Also, give us some code, we can't help you if you don't tell us what you're trying to do

Comment: @FedericoFusco I am using Firestore and trying insert a single record in database.